# save application setting in java & javafx

Tags: java, javafx, save

I'm very new to this topic and trying to gain some understanding. I'm writing an application that allows user to personalize it and create his/own preferences, such as font color, size, certain nodes' positions and etc. While doing my research, I found couple examples using xml files to store users' perferenace.

Is this the best way to store information? Is there a more secure way to do it? since xml file is readable for people and not just the machine.

Comment: I would think you’d want it to be at least somewhat human-readable, if only for troubleshooting purposes.  If you really want it to be unreadable, make all of your preference data Serializable, and use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream to read and write it.  Personally, I always use XML for storing user application settings, or [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) if all of the settings are of minor importance.

Comment: Making it not human-readable, of course, doesn't make it secure. If you want to secure the file, you should do that at the file system level, e.g. by writing to file to a directory only that specific user has access to.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to save more user informations, you can use a database.
But if you need to save one user information, you can use Preferences :

```
Preferences pref;
pref = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(yourClass.class);
pref.put("yourPreferenceName","yourPreferenceValue");
//This create a String preference if it not exists or modify the value if 
//exists

Preferences pref;
pref = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(yourClass.class); 
String preference = pref.get("yourPreferenceName","yourPreferenceValue");
//This give you the value of the preference
```

If you want to know more about the preferences go [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

There is framework named [PreferencesFX](https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/PreferencesFX) which is built using JavaFx (supports Java 8 and Java 11). You can use that framework API according to your use case to save preferences in better way with proper UI.